# NoScript menu disappears in Firefox 52 ESR

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, noscript

I am running Firefox 52 ESR on Linux and have noticed that in recent weeks the menu for the NoScript extension has become intermittently non-functional. It appears to remain functional in browser windows which have been reloaded from my previous session, but when I open a new browser window, the menu button appears but the menu does not open when the button is clicked on.

(Note that I have found a solution to this problem and will now post my solution myself, in case this is a problem that other people are also experiencing.)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my Firefox had NoScript 5.1.8.4 installed, and that this seems to be the last version available for Firefox 52 ESR which is able to be updated automatically via `addons.mozilla.org`.

The NoScript website now notes that: "Updates for NoScript Classic are now served directly from `secure.informaction.com` due to beta channel deprecation and other problems with dual branches on AMO".

The download location for NoScript "Classic" (NoScript for pre-Quantum versions of Firefox, such as Firefox 52 ESR) is linked from [the "get it" page on the NoScript website](https://noscript.net/getit).

(The current version is NoScript Classic 5.1.8.5. The page further notes that NoScript Classic will only continue to be updated until Firefox ESR itself updates to the next ESR release, which will be based on a Quantum version of Firefox.)

Answer (score 0):

Noscript for Firefox 52/Firefox classic: https://secure.informaction.com/download/releases/noscript-5.1.9.xpi